# Raspberry Pi server suddenly stops working

Tags: ssh, networking, apache-httpd, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have Raspberry Pi model 3 B+ which I'm using as a personal development server. Everything works great expect sometimes, out of the blue, my Pi starts acting up. For example ssh gives me a "could not resolve hostname" error and apache gives me a "408 request timeout" error. But, later my raspberry pi starts working normally again. I can't connect to it even if I use its local IP from LAN. It's getting rather annoying and I was hoping there's a way to make it stop acting up.

Comment: If you get `"could not resolve hostname"` error, it's probably something wrong with your router, not the Pi.

Comment: But, I can't even connect to it locally

Comment: what do you mean by `locally`?